# Readability of dict.get with a default value

Tags: python, dictionary, readability

Here is the traditional way to get a `value` by `key` from `dictionary` with a `default` value provided as fallback:

```
value = dictionary.get(key, default)
```

However, I came up with leaving the `default` value omitted in `get` and using the `or`-trick instead:

```
value = dictionary.get(key) or default
```

Would the latter approach be more readable in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not more readable (they're basically the same), and it's more likely to be subtly wrong.

If `dictionary[key]` is *any* falsy value (`None`, the empty string, `list`, `tuple`, etc., or any zero-valued number), the latter produces the `default`. `get` only produces the `default` if the `key` actually doesn't exist.

Comment: Oh no, that would be a lot of mess. Thank you for reminding of such a trivial pitfall.

Answer (score -1):

With regard to readability, I would say they are the same. However as a convention, we are used to `some_dict.get("someKey", None)` 
It also seems runtime difference is marginal.

```sh
python -m timeit '{}.get("key", "someDefault")'
>>> 2000000 loops, best of 5: 144 nsec per loop

python -m timeit '{}.get("key") or "someDefault"'
>>> 2000000 loops, best of 5: 147 nsec per loop
```

When key does exist we see a similar result

```sh
python -m timeit '{"key": "value"}.get("key", "someDefault")'
>>> 2000000 loops, best of 5: 183 nsec per loop

python -m timeit '{"key": "value"}.get("key") or "someDefault"'
>>> 2000000 loops, best of 5: 187 nsec per loop
```

Comment: `.get()` with one argument already implicitly returns `None` as the default. You don't need to pass it at all in that case, and adding `or None`, even if it didn't cause subtle logic errors (all values assumed truthy) would just be replacing `None` with `None` for no reason.

Comment: @ShadowRanger should have specified that None would be a default in OP's case.